# bitmap.compress on a Null Object Reference

Tags: java, android, bitmap

So basically I'm trying to generate a thumbnail image and upload it to server. So this is my code,

```
 Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(intent.getStringExtra("uri"), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
 byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

And this is my uri, I'm getting the uri from previous activity. And it's not null.

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A28682
```

But when I run this code it's showing nullpointerexception at thumnail.compress method.

Error Log..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.buckydroid.app.Utils.FirebaseStorage$2.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.buckydroid..Utils.FirebaseStorage$2.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$1.zzk(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.zze$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: first you'd need to post an MVCE and stack trace. Second this has been answered plenty of times

Comment: How is the `"uri"` extra being added to this `Intent`? Where are you getting the `Uri` from?

Comment: I'm getting the uri from previous intent and i added log message uri is not null @CommonsWare

Comment: "I'm getting the uri from previous intent" -- please edit your question and post the code showing where you are getting this `Uri` from and how you are getting it to the code that you are presently showing in your question.

Comment: Added the error log. And uri is not null. I added a log message and it printed content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A28682

Comment: Learning how to use a debugger will help you save time and effort. This kind of problem takes to debug a couple of minutes while typing and waiting for an answer takes longer

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that the thumbnail is null.

From the [documentation for ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail(java.lang.String,%20int)), "May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported."

So you need to check the result of that call for null, and handle it appropriately.